# How can I drag my form from its client area without disabling functionality of child controls?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-xe2

I have a Delphi XE2 project having components like `Label1`, `BitBtn1` and `Image1`. I have implemented form dragging without the caption bar writing the following code:

```
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure WMNCHitTest(var Msg: TWMNCHitTest) ; message WM_NCHitTest;
```

and

```
procedure TMainForm.WMNCHitTest(var Msg: TWMNCHitTest) ;
begin
  inherited;
  if Msg.Result = htClient then Msg.Result := htCaption;
end;
```

In my form, the `Image1.OnMouseMove` and `Label1.OnClick` events are compulsory for my project, but they are not working. How can I drag the form from the client area except the `Image1` and `Label1` areas? I can do one thing that I may use one `TPanel`, but it will destroy the `GlassFrame` and `SheetOfGlass` properties of my form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to use the position information that is included in the `WM_NCHITTEST` message. Use that to determine whether or not there is a control present at that point. For example you could use the `ControlAtPos` method.

```
procedure TMainForm.WMNCHitTest(var Msg: TWMNCHitTest);
begin
  inherited;
  if ControlAtPos(ScreenToClient(Msg.Pos), True, True, True)=nil then
    if Msg.Result=htClient then
      Msg.Result := htCaption;
end;
```

This will allow dragging only if you have clicked on a point on the form at which there is no control present. You may wish to use an alternative criteria, but use of `Msg.Pos` is the key idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It it exactly the same to my requirement.